# Query mysql returns wrong SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good afternoon friends,

I'm developing an app and I've a page to show "rooms" top. I want to get the sum of app points of all users inside some "room".

I've done this query:

```
SELECT rooms.id, rooms.name, SUM(users.points)
FROM users, room_players, rooms
WHERE users.id = room_players.user AND room_players.room = rooms.id
```

This returns me the sum of the points of all users inside all rooms, and I want the sum of all user's app points by room.

Can someone help me find the error in this query?

Many thanks for now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks basic research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably requires a GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT rooms.id, rooms.name, SUM(users.points) 
FROM users, room_players, rooms 
WHERE users.id = room_players.user AND room_players.room = rooms.id
GROUP BY  rooms.id, rooms.name
```

Using more modern joins:-

```
SELECT rooms.id, rooms.name, SUM(users.points) 
FROM users
INNER JOIN room_players ON users.id = room_players.user
INNER JOIN rooms ON room_players.room = rooms.id
GROUP BY  rooms.id, rooms.name
```

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY room.id to group SUM by rooms

Answer (score 0):

You should use joins and group by look:

```
Select 
   c.id,c.name,sum(a.points) from users a
Inner join room_players b
   On (a.id=b.user)
Inner join rooms c
   On (b.room=c.id)
Group by c.id,c.name
```